# Can't send generic list as a parameter to WCF method

Tags: c#, wcf, generics

I have a WCF service, in which one of the method(or operation contract) uses a generic list of certain type as a parameter, however when i try to consume this service, and call this particular method i get this error

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<CA.CCS.sCmd>' to 'CA.CCS.sCmd[]'
```

I don't know why an object array is expected instead of a generic list in the consumer code.

I want to send that parameter as generic list only, without any conversions on client or server, since it hampers the service performance.

I have found similar questions on stack overflow, but none solving my problem.

your response, or link to other's response will be greatly appreciated.

**Update :** 
I get this window when i try to add service reference, can't find any settings here

[image]

Comment: check the setting in your proxy-generator - maybe you choose to use array over List/ObservableCollection ?

Comment: @Carsten, i haven't made such settings. i don't even know how to check that. Can you guide me please

Comment: you can set those in the "Add Service Reference" dialog

Comment: Updated the question...please check

Comment: you might wonder about that service reference window, it is like this because i am using VS2005 (with installed add-on) to consume a WCF service

Comment: That add-on is a bit old. Why are you using it instead of VS2008 or VS2010?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're still using VS2005, and your proxy generator apparently wants to turn this into an array parameter, you'll just have to convert your `List<T>` to a `T[]` whenever you call this method.

Since you have a `List<T>` instance, you can just use its [`ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x303t819(v=VS.80).aspx) method (supported since .NET 2.0). So instead of calling `SomeMethod(myList)`, you can do `SomeMethod(myList.ToArray())`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to send that parameter as generic list only, without any conversions on client or
>   server, since it hampers the service performance.

There's something I don't understand here: You call a WCF service so either you're misusing it to send large amounts of data or there is no performance problem. Besides, I think you're overworried about performance here. What kind of performance issue do you expect?
Even if you have a very large list: If it contains only reference types the array is just a list of smaller pointers. Only if you have a large amount of structs or other value types there will be performance issues, but still a list of 10,000 double values uses only about 80kb memory.

And if you type this code:

```
List<int> myList = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  myList.Add(i);
```

you've probably coded a bigger performance issue.

Unless you have more information on what could create a problem I'd say use `ToArray()` and be done.

Comment: I do not have very big list of data, but that type of data will be transferred many times by many client over internet on a single server, that's the reason why i was worried, but with the help of your explanation, now i am okay with .ToArray() function. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

specific collection type information is lost in metadata while exported to wsdl, in other words collections send between service and consumers are represented as array.  You can visit [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347850.aspx) and go to 'Customizing Collection Types' section to see how create a custom collection and expose it in contract or see [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dhananjaycoder/2507/)